# Flutter - How to limit time selection in ShowTimePicker in 24H format

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to let the user select only a certain time into business-hours (using 24H format), but I don't know how to achieve this. Is there a way to do it? I tried this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/time_picker_widget but it's not available in 24H format and sometimes it doesn't let you select a "correct" time

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  alwaysUse24HourFormat in MediaQuery like this

```
void inputTimeSelect() async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello! Yeah I Know i have to use alwaysUse24HourFormat, but then how can I limit the time selection?

Comment: its an open issue on flutter git https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23717 there is a workaround for it by using custom piker https://gist.github.com/sclausen/b97e96f33373b8cdc33fcd7bb6f6dfe7

Comment: thank you. However this custom picker seems to be a little buggy: The time selection works, but the hour and minute ui on the left isn't updating. I notice it has a lot of errors for flutter, and i'm trying to "update" the file